# How do I make a crisp pixel art image in processing?

Tags: image, processing

I am using processing.py and I'm trying to load a pixel art image but when I try to make the image big it becomes blurry. How do I avoid this? I am using the loadImage() and image() functions, and I am putting a higher width and height than the actual width and height of the photo into the image() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable aliasing by calling [`noSmooth()`](https://py.processing.org/reference/noSmooth.html) in `setup()`.

If you are using `P2D` or `P3D` you need to set texture sampling to linear: `g.textureSampling(2)`

Here's a modified version of **Processing > Examples > Image > LoadDisplayImage**:

```
def setup():
    size(640, 360)
    global img
    img = loadImage("moonwalk.jpg")    # Load the image into the program
    # make the image really small
    img.resize(32, 18)
    noLoop()
    # disable smoothing
    noSmooth()


def draw():
    # Displays the image scaled up at point (0,0)
    image(img, 0, 0, width, height)
```

and the same for the OpenGL renderer (P2D, P3D):

```
def setup():
    size(640, 360, P2D)
    global img
    img = loadImage("moonwalk.jpg")    # Load the image into the program
    # make the image really small
    img.resize(32, 18)
    noLoop()
    # disable smoothing
    g.textureSampling(2)


def draw():
    # Displays the image scaled up at point (0,0)
    image(img, 0, 0, width, height)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer! That worked.

Comment: I ticked the checkbox. I am new to stack overflow so I don't have enough reputation to upvote you, sorry.